# What does it mean for a REST API to have a `required` response property?

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

Learning about REST APIs and am following https://apihandyman.io/writing-openapi-swagger-specification-tutorial-part-2-the-basics/.

The API can receive two parameters: `username` and `bla`, but only `username` is required by using the `required` keyword.  This makes sense to me.

The API will return `firstname`, `lastname`, and `username`, but only `username` is required by using the `required` keyword. This does not make sense to me. Does the lack of the `required` keyword indicate that the other two might sometimes not be required?  What influences whether they are or are not?

```
paths:
  /persons/{username}:
    get:
      summary: Gets a person
      description: Returns a single person for its username.
      parameters:
        - name: username
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The person's username
          type: string
        - name: bla
          in: query
          description: bla bla bla
          type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: A Person
          schema:
            required:
              - username
            properties:
              firstName:
                type: string
              lastName:
                type: string
              username:
                type: string
        404:
          description: The Person does not exists.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. If a property of a response object is listed in the `required` property list, is must be present in the response object for it to be valid, quite similar to the `required` field in a parameter object. Whether a non-required property is included in the response or not is up to the business logic of your application to decide.

Some more information with pointers to the relevant parts of the specification below:

- The semantics of the `required` property list of a response object is defined as part of the [Schema Object](http://swagger.io/specification/#schemaObject) section of the OpenAPI specification. There it says that the schema object "is based on the JSON Schema Specification Draft 4 and uses a predefined subset of it".
- In the corresponding section on the `required` validation keyword of the [JSON Schema Validation](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor61) specification its semantics is defined as follows:

> 5.4.3.  required
>
> 5.4.3.1.  Valid values
>
> The value of this keyword MUST be an array. This array MUST have at
>   least one element. Elements of this array MUST be strings, and MUST be
>   unique.
>
> 5.4.3.2.  Conditions for successful validation
>
> An object instance is valid against this keyword if its property set
>   contains all elements in this keyword's array value.

- You'll find further examples of how the `required` keyword can be used in the [examples section](http://json-schema.org/example1.html) of the JSON Schema specification or [Part 5, Section 2.2](https://apihandyman.io/writing-openapi-swagger-specification-tutorial-part-5-advanced-input-and-output-modeling/) of the tutorial you're following.